# How do I plot Thomae's function in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, functions

I wanted to plot this function

$$f(x) =\begin{cases}
  1  & \text{if } x= 0 \\
  \tfrac1{q} & \text{if } x = \tfrac{p}{q}\\
                0 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}
 \end{cases}$$

so I wrote

```
FuncThomae[x_] := If[ExactNumberQ[Rationalize[x]], If[x == 0, a = 1, 
                  L = #^-1 & /@ Divisors[Numerator[Rationalize[x]]]], a = 0]
```

and

```
ListDomain[xmin_, xmax_] := Table[Outer[List, {x}, FuncThomae[x]],
                            {x,xmin,xmax,0.001}] // Flatten[#, 1] &
```

My result doesn't take all the real numbers (nor negatives) in its domain, and for $-1$ to $1$, it should have looked like so:

[image: plot of Thomae's function]

but my function does not cater to negatives, nor does it look like the above plot. It looks like this from 2 to 5:

[image: erroneous plot]

Nearly similar, but not quite. Can someone help me to perfect the function?

[Wanted to duplicate this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Non-examples)

Comment: Hi there, is the code you supplied complete, I didn't seem to be able to get it to run successfully ?

Comment: @image_doctor it does run. what was the problem? BTW you need to plot the generated list using the ListDomain function i coded as argument for the ListPlot Function.....

Comment: Outer::ipnfm: "Positive machine-sized integer or Infinity expected at position 3 in Outer[List,{2.},0]." Is the error I get. `a` and `L` seem not to be defined in the code segment you have posted. But as you have an answer, perhaps it isn't important :)

Comment: A tiny reminder: in floating-point arithmetic (which is what *Mathematica* internally uses when plotting), **all numbers are rational**.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd suggest producing a list of rational numbers and then plot the function there, like so:

```
maxq = 100;
fracs = Table[p/q, {q, 2, maxq}, {p, 2, q}] // Flatten // DeleteDuplicates;
pq = {#, 1/Denominator @ #} & /@ fracs;

ListPlot[pq, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image: Thomae's function]

Comment: If you define `pq` as `pq = {#, 1/Denominator[#]}& /@ fracs` you could `ListPlot` `pq` directly without having to transform it first.

Comment: @acl thanks for the lovely answer but the plot is missing the first bit it isnt plotting 1 when x is 0 but anyway thanks....

Comment: btw could you do this for -1 to 1

Comment: @The-Ever-Kid yes that bit is straightforward, so I didn't bother implementing it

Comment: yeah cool thanks...

Comment: thanks to @Heike, David and The-Ever-Kid for improving this mess of an answer!

Comment: @acl When `maxq=10`, the point $\{ \frac{1}{10}, \frac{1}{10} \}$ is missing from `pq`.  Perhaps we should use `Table[p/q, {q, 2, maxq}, {p, 1, q}]` instead?

Comment: @Michael Yes, I suppose you're right (I admit that I lifted this fragment from some code I wrote for a different purpose, which is why it is such a mess...)

Answer (score 13):

Why not use `DiscretePlot` directly?

```
DiscretePlot[1/Denominator[Rationalize[x]], {x, -1, 1, 1/(2*3*4*5*6*7)}, 
       PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Filling -> None, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Abs[x] != 1]]
```

The `RegionFunction` throws out the cases where $\frac{p}{q}=1$.

[image: Thomae function]

Answer (score 12):

Another possibility that avoids the generation of fractions not in lowest terms (and thus the use of `Union[]` or `DeleteDuplicates[]`) rests on generating a [Farey sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FareySequence.html), and then applying the Dirichlet-Thomae function to that:

```
farey[n_Integer?Positive] := Module[{v = 0, w = 1, p = 1, q = n, t},
  Join[{0, 1/n}, Flatten[Last[
     Reap[While[p < q,
       t = Quotient[n + w, q];
       {{p, v}, {q, w}} = {{t p - v, p}, {t q - w, q}};
       Sow[p/q]]]
     ]]]]

ListPlot[{#, 1/Denominator[#]} & /@ farey[100], Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image: Thomae's function applied to the Farey sequence]

Comment: (Nowadays, one would use the built-in `FareySequence[]`.)

Comment: That would make the code 
```ListPlot[{#, 1/Denominator[#]} & /@ FareySequence[100], Frame -> True,
  PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick look at a Table of the outcomes of your code shows pretty much what the problem is. If

```
FuncThomae[x_] := If[
  ExactNumberQ[Rationalize[x]],
  If[x == 0,
   1,
   L = #^-1 & /@ Divisors[Numerator[Rationalize[x]]]
   ]
  , 0]
```

then `Table[FuncThomae[x], {x, 0, 1, 0.1}]` produces

```
{1, {1}, {1}, {1, 1/3}, {1, 1/2}, {1}, {1, 1/3},
  {1, 1/7}, {1, 1/2, 1/4}, {1, 1/3, 1/9}, {1}}
```

which makes it clear that the function is not producing numbers as output like it should.

If you want a working functional version of the Thomae function, the naive try

```
FuncThomae[x_] := If[
  ExactNumberQ[Rationalize[x]],
  If[x == 0,
   1,
   1/Denominator[Rationalize[x]]
   ]
  , 0
  ]
```

does work, and you do not need to worry about eliminating common factors with the numerator before asking for the Denominator because the latter does the procedure as standard. (If not, what unique number could it produce?) With that version, `Table[FuncThomae[x], {x, 0, 1, 0.1}]` produces

```
{1, 1/10, 1/5, 1/10, 1/5, 1/2, 1/5, 1/10, 1/5, 1/10, 1}
```

and if you graph it using, say, `DiscretePlot[FuncThomae[x], {x, 0, 1, 0.001}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 Axes -> False]`, you get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note, however, that this plot is not correct, because any discrete scan is going to miss points like $f(1/3)=1/3$. To get those points, run a plot like

```
ListPlot[
 Flatten[Table[
   {p/q, FuncThomae[p/q]}
   , {p, 0, 100}, {q, 1, 100}], 1]
 , PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Axes -> False
 ]
```

to produce

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for GCD has this example.

```
ListPlot[{#, GCD[1, #]} & /@ 
  Union[Flatten[Table[i/j, {j, 40}, {i, 2 j}]]]]
```

The documentation states,

> Form the GCDs of 1 with rational numbers:

This is the fourth part for Neat Examples for GCD. GCD and Thomae's function are related. The Wikipedia page for Greatest Common Divisor mentions Thomae's function.