# Implementing the Farey sequence efficiently

Tags: recursion, number-theory

There is of course the silly implementation:

```
FareySequence[n_] := Union[Flatten[Table[j/i, {i, 1, n}, {j, 0, i}]]]
```

However, there are numerous properties and confinements of Farey sequences (that can be used, **potentially**, in an indirect manner).

This calls for a very simple, and, very efficient recurring/functional implementation, exhibiting *Superiority*. But I'm new to *Mathematica* and can't find the right combination of built-in functions, and pure functions..

Ideas?

Comment: [Hmm...](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5489)

Comment: I saw the implementation in [the link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5489). Isn't there a simpler implementation?

Comment: Your implementation is certainly simpler. Of course, it's also less efficient.

Comment: Actually, the OPs code comes from here: http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=489620 or here http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FareySequence/ whichever came first.

Comment: @J.M. I'm sure there is a more elegant, more efficient, simpler to read and comprehend, method. Better than all those mentioned, because it is all very simple. I'll give it a go with a rit or 2 later.... :P

Comment: Be my guest, then. :)

Comment: There are many relationships between members of the Farey sequence. For instance, if a/b and c/d are members, then the mediant (a+c)/(b+d) is in the sequence. This property might be easier to exploit than the one you've given.

Comment: What you said was not correct, but makes you wonder.

Comment: The mediant property is well known, see for instance: http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~mcs103480/farey-icip-100525.pdf

Comment: @bill, there are restrictions to be imposed on the denominators for the constructed mediant to be a proper member of the $k$th Farey sequence, of course.

Comment: Right, it holds as long as the denominator is not larger than `k` -- the `DeleteCases` in the answer removes those extra ones.

Comment: @J.M. Some ideas also here http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1896/code-challenge-farey-sequence-ii

Comment: @bel, that just counts the number of terms in the Farey sequence. That is most easily done in *Mathematica*, which has `EulerPhi[]`.

Comment: @J.M. Then I misread it. Sorry.

Comment: @J.M. Nevertheless, `EulerPhi[]` can be handy even for our purposes... Along with another 10 (or so) tricks... (as of now) :) Let's start a most efficient Farey competition! The winner.. uumm.. will be awarded a book about Number Theory.. or... candy.

Comment: I think the problem with finding a recursive solution using the cited property is that the property is not strictly speaking a recurrence relation, since $D_k$ depends on $F_k$.  Indeed for any $F_{k-1}$, there are infinitely many solutions for $F_k$ (depending on the order).

Comment: @MichaelE2 you are absolutely correct. Your comment is Superior. :) Do you think I should remake the question? So It'll be Superior? This Farey sequence is packed with logic/rules and confinments, up to a point where I think it can be implmented on/by pure logic :)

Comment: Yes, perhaps you should clarify whether you want an efficient way to generate the Farey sequences or to be shown how to implement certain properties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik in their book Concrete Mathematics
(pages 118 and 150) discuss the Farey series. Their recurrence
does not require finding `Subsets`, computing the elements in
order starting with $0/1$ and $1/n$. Although very fast, `Subsets`
can use too much memory when very large $n$ are required, as for
some PE problems.

```
FareyIterate[{f1_,f2_},n_Integer]:=
   {f2,(#*Numerator[f2]-Numerator[f1])/(#*Denominator[f2]-Denominator[f1])}&
   [Floor[(Denominator[f1]+n)/Denominator[f2]]]

FareyLength[n_Integer]:=Total[EulerPhi[Range[n]]] + 1

ConcreteFarey[n_]:=NestList[FareyIterate[#,n]&, {0, 1/n}, FareyLength[n]-1][[All,1]]
```

A `NestWhile` formulation is possible to pick out
certain values without storing the entire list. Nevertheless,
this function is only half as fast as `farey2[n]` of @Michael E2
and @J.M.

Comment: This is effectively the method I used for plotting Thomae's function (which I linked to in the comments), but was glibly dismissed by the OP. On that note, I'd use `NestWhile[]` if I wanted to avoid the use of `EulerPhi[]`, and would replace `Floor[(Denominator[f1]+n)/Denominator[f2]]` with `Quotient[Denominator[f1] + n, Denominator[f2]]`.

Comment: Thank you @J.M. for these performance tips. I would also be interested to know your experience with `GCD` versus `CoprimeQ` in `farey2[n]`. I've found `GCD` faster in some cases...

Comment: If you use `Divide @@@  NestList[FareyIterate[#, n] &, {0, 1, 1, n}, FareyLength[n] - 1][[All, 1 ;; 2]]` for `ConcreteFarey` and alter to `FareyIterate[{f1N_, f1D_, f2N_, f2D_}, n_Integer]` etc -- J.M. beat me to recommending `Quotient` -- the speed is about halfway between your original and `farey2`.  (`Integers` are faster than `Rationals`.)

Comment: @Michael E2: Brilliant. Your recommendations bring the timings down to 2/3 of previous values, much closer to those of `farey2[n]`.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a way to exploit the mediant property of the Farey series. To calculate the mediant:

```
med[{a_, b_}] := (Numerator[a] + Numerator[b])/(Denominator[a] + Denominator[b]);
```

Then the Farey series is:

```
farey[n_] := farey[n] = DeleteCases[ Riffle[
     farey[n - 1], med /@ Partition[farey[n - 1], 2, 1]], _?(Denominator[#] > n &)];
```

with initial conditions

```
farey[2]={0,1/2,1}
```

Now you can get `farey[n]` for any fixed `n` straightforwardly.

Comment: `med[v_List] := Total[Numerator[v]]/Total[Denominator[v]]` is a bit more compact.

Comment: That's good, but you know, this whole approach doesn't seem any faster than the simple way!

Comment: Well, the OP did dismiss my proposal so glibly...

Comment: I'll do some performance testing on this marble. Though I'm working on one my self....

Comment: This implementation is slowest thus far as far as I can check

Comment: @Dror Well, you did ask for a functional approach and this certainly provides it. Also, you never indicated that speed was your primary concern and I see no immediate reason that it should be. The primary advantage of this approach that I see is the clarity provided by its immediate connection to the mediant. By removing the `DeleteCases` step, for example, we essentially recover the Stern-Brocot tree.

Comment: @MarkMcClure , I guess you are right. Obviously, the performance is more than "enough" and the recovery of Stern-Brocot tree obtained by merely removing the head is quite nice. Though, I know there are many many mathematical facts that could be harnessed, for the sake of _elegance_, simplicity, **readability** (and performance!!!) among others, while still maintaining functional form.. I actually am inclined to implement it... But I don't have time now.

Comment: @dror - It is interesting that the functional answer is so much slower than the "simple" answer. Maybe it's because the very basic commands like `Union` and `Table` are quicker than comparatively obscure commands like `Numerator` and `DeleteCases`.

Comment: @bills Well, obviously. Regarding that, I don't think It's TOO weird, that initially I was hoping for a step up in performance. By the way, it isn't much slower... It's same'ish-- :)

Comment: @bills Aaaaaaaaaand, I do VERY MUCH seriously thank you for the time you spent on my question, and the new tricks I learned from your implementation. :)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a functional way to use the property (the property, which has been removed from the original question, was $N'/D' = N/D + 1/D'D$ or equivalently $N'D-D'N=1$):

```
farey1[n_] := 
 NestWhileList[
   With[{num0 = Numerator[#], den0 = Denominator[#]},
     First @ Minimize[{num/den, 
       num den0 - num0 den == 1 && 1 <= den <= n && 1 <= num <= n},
       {num, den}, Integers]] &,
   1/n,
   # < 1 - 1/n &]
```

Mighty slow:

```
foo1 = farey1[15]; // Timing
(* {0.441386, Null} *)
```

Here's faster way, without using the property:

```
farey2[n_] := Sort @ Pick[Rational @@@ #, GCD @@ Transpose@#, 1] &@ Subsets[Range[n], {2}];

foo2 = Farey2[15]; // Timing
(* {0.000193, Null} *)
```

Following J.M.'s comment, this is more succinct:

```
farey2[n_] := Sort @ Pick[Divide @@@ #, CoprimeQ @@@ #] &@ Subsets[Range[n], {2}];
```

Both methods give the "interior" of the traditional sequence, omitting 0 and 1:

```
farey1[5]
(* {1/5, 1/4, 1/3, 2/5, 1/2, 3/5, 2/3, 3/4, 4/5} *)
```

Comment: Any reason why you use `Rational @@@ (* stuff *)` instead of `Divide @@@ (* stuff *)`? Anyway, something for your consideration: `Sort[Pick[Divide @@@ #, CoprimeQ @@@ #]] &[Subsets[Range[n], {2}]]`.

Comment: @J.M. No particular reason for `Rational` -- any reason not to?  Thanks for the `CoprimeQ` tip -- it's a bit faster by a little.

Comment: "any reason not to?" - not really; I was asking out of curiosity more than anything, since I conventionally use `Divide` in such situations.

Comment: @J.M. In my answer I adapted some pre-`Pick` code from way back, which had `Rational`.  At the time, I may have thought it was more direct since `Divide[1, 2]` evaluates to `Rational[1, 2]`.  It seems to be about 5% faster, but that hardly matters here.

Answer (score 5):

And with an updated Mathematica, there is an updated (and far simpler) answer: FareySequence is now built in. For example:

```
FareySequence[4]
{0, 1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a very nice, and relatively new (2008) algorithm for the Farey sequence that is extremely efficient. It computes any Farey sequence in just one pass, in order, with very little compute time or overhead.

It can be found on Wikipedia (Farey Sequence) and is cited there as:

Routledge, Norman (March 2008). "Computing Farey series". The Mathematical Gazette. Vol. 92, no. 523. pp. 55–62.

In javascript:

```
function farey(n) {
  let a = 0,
      b = 1,
      c = 1,
      d = n,
      result = "0/1";

  while (c <= n) {
    let k = Math.floor((n + b) / d);
    let a_new = a,
        b_new = b,
        c_new = c,
        d_new = d;

    a = c_new;
    b = d_new;
    c = k * c_new - a_new;
    d = k * d_new - b_new;
    result += `, ${a}/${b}`;
  }

  return result;
}
```

farey(6) returns:

0/1, 1/6, 1/5, 1/4, 1/3, 2/5, 1/2, 3/5, 2/3, 3/4, 4/5, 5/6, 1/1

This is extraordinary because it doesn't need recursion, nor nested loops, nor insertion within a list (only append the next value, in order). It also does not need GCD, as it immediately finds the reduced form of each term with the clever use of k in the algorithm.

I think this might satisfy the OP's request for an algorithm exhibiting "superiority."

A good explanation of how it works is in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Providing the Mathematic code for this algorithm would be a service to the community.

Comment: @bgodfrey I think the response by Kenny Colnago effectively provides said code.