# Cantor Pairing Function

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I'm inspecting the Cantor pairing function, that we can find on this link [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function).

But the strange thing is that *Mathematica* is outputting a wrong result to me. The code below shows the strange behavior. When we plot the `Q2N1` function, the $y$-axis does not corresponds to the correct value. See:

```
Q2N0[q_] := (Numerator[q] + Denominator[q] + 1)
            (Numerator[q] + Denominator[q])/2 + Denominator[q]

Q2N[q_] := Q2N0[Rationalize[q]]

Q2N1[q_] := Q2N[N[q, 10]]

Q2N1[0.2]

Out[13]= 26

Plot[Q2N1[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: the plot]

As we can see, confronting the code with the plot, when `x = 0.2` the correct value is `26`, but *Mathematica* plot function returns a value near of `2.25`. The truth is all returned values should be integers or very near to integers, so `2.25` could never be a result. Crazy.

Why this is happening? And, how can we have the correct output?

**Edit**

I think that I reached a plot with *Mathematica*, using some ideas presented in the answers. Looks like the problem was with `Rationalize`. Doing some tests I have found that need to pass a `0` argument, without it the function 'ignores' `Rationalize`. See below:

```
Q2N0[q_] := (Numerator[q] + Denominator[q] + 1)
            (Numerator[q] + Denominator[q])/2 + Denominator[q]

Q2N1[q_] := Q2N0[Rationalize[q, 0]]

Plot[Q2N1[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: plot again]

But I'm still having a problem. `FindRoot` now brings a strange result. Crazy bis =)

Let's see:

```
In[125]:= Rationalize[5.588723439378913`, 0]

Out[125]= 97873229/17512627

In[127]:= Q2N1[5.588723439378913`]

Out[127]= 6656947957631923

In[130]:= FindRoot[Q2N1[x] == 26, {x, 0.1}]

Out[130]= {x -> 5.58872}
```

But `Q2N1` is a bijection and `Q2N1[x] == 26` when `x` is `0.2`. Even if was not a bijection, `Q2N1[5.588723439378913]` evaluates to `6656947957631923` instead of `26`. (See that when I copied and paste `5.58872`, *Mathematica* paste `5.588723439378913` instead of `5.58872`).

**So, how can we manipulate this function that it will plot OK (already achieved as looks like) and the `FindRoot` will find the correct root (or at least try it, instead of brings some strange `5.58872` result?**

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: I have edited. I think now is a bit clear.

Comment: `Q2N` is not continuous.  Although `Q2N[.2]` is `26`, `Q2N[.211]` is `734866`.  By the way, because `Q2N` produces integers, `Q2N1` merely reproduces the output of `Q2N`.

Comment: I agree, but, as you can see in the image, when `x=0.2` the y axis is about `2.25` and not an integer. This plot could be a very crazy with several values jumping to strange areas, but not this strange moody curve...

Comment: The plot you actually have is `Q2N0[x]`.  Evidently, `q` is not being passed in `Rationalize` form.  Strange.

Comment: Hum interesting. Looks like this is true. Strange to me. So, can we rewrite this function to give us the expected results?

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to bill's plotting approach would be to only evaluate the pairing function at the members of the [Farey sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FareySequence.html) (similar to the approach in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5522)). Thus,

```
q2N0[q_Rational] := (Numerator[q] + Denominator[q] + 1)
                    (Numerator[q] + Denominator[q])/2 + Denominator[q]

ListPlot[{#, q2N0[#]} & /@ FareySequence[500], PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[1/10]]
```

[image: Cantor pairing function evaluated at the Farey sequence]

Answer (score 3):

The problem with discontinuity is severe. One approach to understanding this function is to control exactly what values get evaluated (rather than letting this be handled by `Plot`). For example, here it is for all fractions between $0$ and $1$ with increment of $1/10000$:

```
q2N0[q_Rational] := (Numerator[q] + Denominator[q] + 1) 
            (Numerator[q] + Denominator[q])/2 + Denominator[q]; 
xvals = Rationalize[Range[0, 1, 0.0001]];
list = q2N0[#] & /@ xvals;
ListPlot[Thread[{xvals, list}]]
```

[image: Cantor pairing plot]

As stated by the OP, the function values are all integers, but they bounce around a lot. I do not think this function is well defined for real numbers, but only for rationals. For example, as I have defined it above, `q2N0[2/10]` makes sense and is equal to 26 (as you expect) but `q2N0[0.2]` is undefined. You need to be careful with the domain. You can get another view of the function by plotting using `ListLinePlot` instead of `ListPlot`.

Comment: Very interesting. Nice plot. Using your idea I could get a nice plot (and I think it is OK, as looks like). But `FindRoot` still breaks... please see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

`FindRoot` cannot provide answers to `Q2N[x] == 26`, because `Q2N` (and, equivalently, `Q2N1`) is not a differentiable function.  However, a solution clearly exists, which is the whole point of Cantor Pairing.  In fact, `Solve` provides the answer.

```
Solve[26 == (n + d + 1) (n + d)/2 + d && n > 0 && d > 0, {n, d}, Integers]
(* {{n -> 1, d -> 5}} *)
```

where `n` and `d` are shorthand for `Numerator[x]` and `Denominator[x]`.  The result is as expected.

More difficult cases are

```
Q2N[.21]
(* 7481 *)
Solve[7481 == (n + d + 1) (n + d)/2 + d && n > 0 && d > 0, {n, d}, Integers]
(* {{n -> 21, d -> 100}} *)

Q2N[.213]
(* 737291 *)
Solve[737291 == (n + d + 1) (n + d)/2 + d && n > 0 && d > 0, {n, d}, Integers]
(* {{n -> 213, d -> 1000}} *)

Q2N[.2112]
(* 287528 *)
Solve[287528 == (n + d + 1) (n + d)/2 + d && n > 0 && d > 0, {n, d}, Integers]
(* {{n -> 132, d -> 625}} *)
```

again as expected.  (`N[132/625]` is, indeed, precisely `0.2112`.)

**Plot of First 1000 Q2N**

For completeness, the solutions for the first 1000 values of `Q2N` can be plotted.

```
ListPlot[Table[{i, n/d /. Flatten@Solve[i == (n + d + 1) (n + d)/2 + d && n > 0 && d > 0,
   {n, d}, Integers]}, {i, 1000}], AxesLabel -> {"Q2N[x]", x}]
```

[image]

Note that a solution does not exist for every `i`, although one does for most `i` (e.g., `913` of the first `1000`).

Comment: Talking of values for which no solution exist... a curious sequence appears: `Select[Range@100, Resolve[!Exists[{n, d}, n > 0 && d > 0, # == (n + d + 1) (n + d)/2 + d], Integers] &] (* {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 14, 15, 20, 21, 27, 28, 35, 36, 44, 45, 54, 55, 65, 66, 77, 78, 90, 91} *)`. It would appear to be OEIS sequence [A117142](https://oeis.org/A117142).

Comment: @kirma  Interesting.  What do you make of it?  Thanks.

Comment: I fear nothing in particular, but it is interesting to see that the sequence is defined in quite different terms in OEIS, and also a lone paper talking of "lexnumbers", whatever they are.