# How do I plot a Dirichlet function?

Tags: plotting, visualization

How to plot this function in *Mathematica*?

[image: Dirichlet function]

Comment: Look at [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html)

Comment: I think this is impossible. The Dirichlet function is discontinuous at each point of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Or, simpler, `Plot[{0, 1}, {x, -1, 2}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1/2, 3/2}}]`. Anyway, you can't really plot Dirichlet function...

Comment: A more interesting question would be to plot [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function).

Comment: @Rahul . You can download MMA notebook in `Thomae's function` click here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/NumberTheory/DirichletFunction.nb

Comment: The Thomae case [has been dealt with before](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5489).

Answer (score 4):

```
dirichlet[x_] := If[IntegerQ[Numerator[Rationalize[x]]], 1, 0]

dirichlet[1.24898]
dirichlet[Pi]
```

> 1
>
> 0

Comment: How about dirichlet[N[Sqrt[Pi/Exp[1]], 10]]?

Comment: @user64494 gives me 0 in MMA11.1 - is that wrong?

Comment: Where is the plot? :)

Comment: @Sumit: Up to the definition, it should result 1.

Comment: @Kuba, I don't have a rational answer for that.

Comment: @user64494, what would be the rationalised form for `Sqrt[Pi/Exp[1]]`?

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can't really plot this function, since it is discontinuous everywhere. But you can fake it:

```
d[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, Abs[Rationalize[x, 0.01] - x] > 0.004}, {0, True}}]; 
DiscretePlot[d[x], {x, 0, 1, 0.001}]
```

[image]

By playing with the second argument of the Rationalize and the value in the inequality, you can change the detailed appearance of the function.

Answer (score 2):

Faked  by `ListLinePlot` and improved code borrowed from [bill s](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1783/bill-s)

```
d[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, Abs[Rationalize[x, 0.0003] - x] > 0.0002}, {0,True}}];
ListLinePlot[Table[{x, d[x]}, {x, -1/2, 1, 0.0001}], 
MeshStyle -> PointSize[Small], Mesh -> {Range[-1/2, 1, 0.0001]}, 
MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, MeshShading -> {White, White}, 
PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1/2, 3/2}}, 
PlotLegends -> {"Dirichlet function"}]
```

[image]